# How to send dynamic values in dataLayer.push() method?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am working on e-commerce website, where I am using Google Tag Manager(GTM) to analyse the data flow. So now I need to send some e-commerce booking data to GTM. For single cart value all looks ok. But when multiple cart values are there,I am not able to format the data-layer array how I am in need of. Below code works for single cart value, please help me to do the same for multiple cart items.

```
foreach($_SESSION['test']['item'] as $key => $value) {
      dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'Thankspage',
        'itemname': [
        {
        'name': '<?php echo $_SESSION['test']['item']['item-name']; ?>',
        'itemCode': '<?php echo $_SESSION['test']['item']['itemCode']; ?>',
        'price': '<?php echo $_SESSION['test']['item']['item-price']; ?>'
        }],
        'totalprice': '<?php echo $_SESSION['test']['total-price']; ?>',
      });
}
```

I tried using this foreach loop but i will get `'event': 'Thankspage'` multiple times, i need structure like below if there are multiple items:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'Thankspage',
  'itemname': [
  {
  'name': 'Business Analysis Essentials',
  'itemCode': 'BA-ESS',
  'price': '1145.00'
  },
  {
  'name': 'BABOK Foundation',
  'itemCode': 'CGABAB3FCD',
  'price': '595.00'
  }],
  'totalprice': '1740.00'
});
```

please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending the dataLayer for every iteration of your for loop, what you need to do is create the array first and then send all of the data together. For example (code below not tested):

```
var itemsArray = []; //initialize empty array
var totalPrice; //initialize total price

foreach($_SESSION['test']['item'] as $key => $value) {
    //code below will add all items in the itemsArray (no push to GTM yet)
    itemsArray.push(
      {
      'name': '<?php echo $_SESSION['test']['item']['item-name']; ?>',
      'itemCode': '<?php echo $_SESSION['test']['item']['itemCode']; ?>',
      'price': '<?php echo $_SESSION['test']['item']['item-price']; ?>'
      }     
    });
    totalPrice = '<?php echo $_SESSION['test']['total-price']; ?>';
}

//once all items are in the itemsArray we will push the event to dataLayer
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'Thankspage',
    'itemname': itemsArray,
    'totalprice': totalPrice,
});
```